# Ionic2 + Angular2 passing configuration to dependency

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I want to set global configuration file or from `app.ts`.

Pass configuration, which can be used on our dependency injection automatically

Api.ts Service

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http'

@Injectable()
export class Api {

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    login (username, password)
    {
        return this.http.get(`../?client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${clientSecret}&grant_type=password&username=${username}&password=${password}`).map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

How can I pass client id and client secret to api dependency globally from typescript angular2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a file with your credentials

credentials.ts

```
export var credentials = {
  client_id: 1234,
  client_secret: 'secret'
}
```

And import it into your file

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http'
import {credentials} from 'credentials'

@Injectable()
export class Api {

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    login (username, password)
    {
        return this.http.get('../?client_id=' + credentials.client_id + '&client_secret=' + credentials.client_secret + '&grant_type=password&username=${username}&password=${password}`).map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```